# How do I migrate Google Drive from 'Google Apps for Business' account to a personal Google Drive account

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace

I want to migrate Google Drive from a 'Google Apps for Business' account to a personal Google Drive account, as my company has decided to move to office365+sharepoint, and close down the Google Apps for Business account.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/26245/19350

Answer (score 1):

You can use Backupify's free [Snapshot for Google Apps](https://www.backupify.com/free-tools/snapshot-google-apps) tool to accomplish this.

> Snapshot for Google Apps extracts all the Gmail & Gchat messages, Google Drive documents, Google Calendar events, Google Contacts entries and Google Sites data from a single Google Apps user account.

You can then import that data into another Google (or Google Apps) account.

You'll have to add the app as a Google Apps administrator.