# How to migrate apps and stuff to g suite from regular gmail account

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive, google-account, google-workspace-for-business, google-drive-sharing

**Summary**

How can I use my new G Suite identity in my existing Google Apps Script and other google back-end services? Even a vague concept clarification or pointer in the right direction would be helpful.

My new G Suite user apparently has the good quota limit but all my app config is under my old gmail. Had I known I would have created G Suite first and based my app off of that from the get go.

**Current Situation**

Here's what I've done up until this point. I didn't know any better:

1. I got a domain (mycompany.com)
2. I created an email with that domain (darkstarman@mycompany.com)
3. I created a gmail account for my business (mycompany@gmail.com) and forwarded all that to my domain email. No one has the gmail address, just my domain email address.
4. I created google apps script based on that email mycompany@gmail.com
5. Now there's a whole bunch of IT stuff hanging off of that mycompany@gmail.com user (google apps script, firebase, storage, sheets, google drive, etc)
6. All was fine with the world
7. Then one day, when debugging my app, I hit a quota. I found out if I upgrade to G Suite basic, my quota will go up from 20k url calls to 100k url calls / day for $6 / mo. I decided "hey that's worth it if I want my app to actually work under production loads."
8. I used my domain email to create a G Suite basic account. It didn't ask or care if I already had a gmail account that I'd like to merge with or use.

**Tried so far**

This isn't something you can just google to find the answer if you don't know what to search under.

And the google help forums, eh, let's just say I'm not too optimistic about posting this there, as I see every question answered with almost an unimaginable level of incompetence initially, until months pass and another user posts an answer (so it's basically user community self-help).

And navigating the control panels? I'm a dev not an admin. I suffer from Dashboard Dizziness. But more importantly, if you don't know what you're doing you can destroy entire apps with one click and dashboards typically don't advise you before you do something terribly stupid other than to meekly ask "are you sure?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bad news are that the ownership of files stored in Google Drive, including Google Apps Script stand-alone projects, can't be transferred from a personal account to a G Suite account.

One alternative is to share the files with the G Suite account then make a copy of this files. In the case of Google Apps Script projects, another alternative is to create a new project then import the code by using CLASP or [Google Apps Script GitHub Assistant](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-apps-script-github/lfjcgcmkmjjlieihflfhjopckgpelofo?hl=en).

Regarding "other Google back-end services", it depends on each service. Some of them that aren't part of G Suite, support having multiple administrators and have their own billing. Please look at the corresponding help center.

Related

- [Easiest way to transfer Google data between accounts](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/26245/88163)
- [How can I transfer ownership of a file in Google Drive that isn't part of Docs?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/114423/88163)